# google calendar api v3 calendar.events.list and using timeMax,timeMin in javascript

Tags: javascript, calendar, google-calendar-api

```
var resource = {
    ///  "kind": "calendar#event",

    "alwaysIncludeEmail" : "true",
    "singleEvents" : "true",
    "orderBy" : "startTime",
    "timeMax": {
        "dateTime": "2013-10-01T00:00:00+10:00" //maxDate.toISOString()
    },
    "timeMin": {
        "dateTime":  "2013-08-29T00:00:00+10:00" //startDateMin.toISOString()
    }
};

var calendar_id = new calendarIds();

var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
    'calendarId': calendar_id.source,
    'resource': resource
});

....

request.execute(function(resp){
```

this javascript is returning ALL events in the calendar !!!!!

plugging those time values into [v3 api explorer](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)
and the correct time range of events return.

so how the freak to get my javascript to do the same ? i tried heaps of
permutations, whys it so freaking hard this google api stuff.......

need a working example please

Comment: if the request is rewritten as

 var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
   'calendarId': calendar_id,
   "singleEvents" : true,
   "orderBy" : "startTime",
   "timeMin":  startDate.toISOString(),
   "timeMax":  maxDate.toISOString()
 });

  request.execute(function(resp){

it now works!

Answer (score 2):

if the request is rewritten as

```
 var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': calendar_id,
      "singleEvents" : true,
      "orderBy" : "startTime",
      "timeMin":  startDate.toISOString(),
      "timeMax":  maxDate.toISOString()
    });

  request.execute(function(resp){
```

it now works!

there is some confusion with that "resource" parameter. Obviously i saw an example that worked using the insert() api. But that is the Events resource as documented for insert().

Comment: It appears that `singleEvents` is a must-have in order to have timeMin and timeMax work properly

Answer (score 1):

When using Google Script, with API v2 and v3, you can write:

```
var calendar_id = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('My Test Calendar')[0];
var start_date = new Date();
var query = Calendar.Events.list(calendar_id, {timeMin: start_date.toISOString()});
var events = query.items;
```

Tricks in the `Calendar.Events.list` call is that the first parameter is the calendar id, the second is an object. When passing dates, need to use `x.toISOString()`.